# Интересует вопрос на нагрузку запроса SQL

Tags: безопасность, sql

Есть например простенький запрос:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT `last_time` FROM `users` WHERE `id` = 1");
$data = mysql_fetch_array($query);
```

Если например я пошлю огромное количество запросов на сайт с этим 1-м запросом, то он сляжет, учитывая то, что нет никаких защит?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

замучаетесь этим запросом "класть" сайт. майэскуэль кэширует таки запросы)